# Mysql query works in Phpmyadmin but not works in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables
the first one is **cont_details**

```
     -------------- --------------
    | cont_details_id  | cont_no |
     -----------------------------
    |  1                |   A001 |
    |  2                |   A002 |
    |  3                |   A003 |
    ------------------------------
```

and the second one is **cont_sold_tmp**

```
     --------------
    | id | cont_no |
     --------------
    |  1 |   1    |
    |  2 |   3    |
    ----------------
```

now i need to select from table **cont_details** table which are not in **temp_cont**

so i used this query

`select * from cont_details left join cont_sold_tmp on cont_details.cont_details_id = cont_sold_tmp.cont_no where cont_sold_tmp.cont_no is null`

This query works perfectly when i check in PhpmyAdmin but when i use it in HTMl, not working

```
<select name="cont_no"  id="cont_no" data-rel="chosen">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <?php
       $qry = mysql_query("select * from cont_details left join cont_sold_tmp on cont_details.cont_details_id = cont_sold_tmp.cont_no where cont_sold_tmp.cont_no is null");
           while($res = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
              {
         ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $res["cont_details_id"];?>">
           <?php echo $res["cont_no"];?>
      </option>
     <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

Database connections are working perfectly, instead of join query i just checked with the simple query "**select * from cont_details**" its shows all the records. but when i use this join query. i dont get any records in dropdown

Comment: What error are you getting..?

Comment: Maybe phpmyadmin and your php script use a different user with different permissions?

Comment: How do you mean not working?

Comment: In what way is it "not working"?  Can you provide us with an error message?

Comment: DB connection error may be there

Comment: You're not doing any error checking at all and it appears as though you're not even connecting to the database. Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)** instead, and **use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo).

Comment: no errors, but i dont get any records in dropdown @prashant

Comment: Show us the part where you connect to the database.

Comment: Another PHP coder using `mysql_*` , you may goto hell because of Not securing PHP application ! :)

Comment: Database connections are working perfectly, instead of join query i just checked with this query "select * from cont_details" its shows all the records. but when i use this join query. i dont get any records

Comment: What is the output from your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And finally found the mistake what i did -_-

```
select cont_details.cont_details_id as cont_details_id, 
cont_details.cont_no as cont_no
from cont_details left join cont_sold_tmp
on cont_details.cont_details_id = cont_sold_tmp.cont_no
where cont_sold_tmp.cont_no is NULL
```

after combining tables, i didn't choose column correctly with table name (.)

so the result when i use 
`<option value="<?php echo $res["cont_details_id"];?>">` , it doesnt exits there so its show empty

thank you for ur replys :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
```

Comment: User print_r($res) in `   while($res = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
              {print_r($res)` AND in Inspect element , check what is appearing.

Comment: Array ( [0] => 1000 [cont_price] => 1000 [1] => 3 [cont_details_id] => 3 [2] => A003 [cont_no] => [3] => 45 [cont_size] => 45 [4] => HC [cont_type] => HC [5] => 30480 Kgs [cont_tonnage] => 30480 Kgs [6] => 2013 [yom] => 2013 [7] => CARGO WORTHY [cont_condition] => CARGO WORTHY [8] => 1 [cont_buying_id] => 1 [9] => 70 [exc_rate] => 70 [10] => [cont_sold_tmp_id] => [11] => [12] => [price] => [13] => [cont_selling_id] => )    yaa its getting value but when i use the query inside dropdown returns nothing

Comment: See ` [cont_no] => ` You get Blank value for cont_no . Getting ?

Comment: cont_details.cont_details_id as cont_details_id, 
cont_details.cont_no as cont_no

Comment: @Vijay , nice , you can accept answer and upvote as i helped you in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,use "IS NULL" instead of "is null":

```
$qry = mysql_query("select * from cont_details left join cont_sold_tmp on cont_details.cont_details_id = cont_sold_tmp.cont_no where cont_sold_tmp.cont_no IS NULL");
```

Comment: Sorry to be off-topic but which university should i join in India for web developing and programming

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com But is there any scope in India related to PHP programming

Comment: @Hudixt , please Visit my profile and mail me , I can answer your question there as This section diverts from Question.Thanks